# Audio Scrubber follows timeline

Tags: javascript, css, html, audio

I created an audio player that I would like the scrubber (instead of a circle) be a bar that follows and fills up the played part of a song with a different color. With that being said, i thought I could simply make the bar `100%` and give it a negative `left` value, however this is not the case. For some reason, I can't get it to follow the distance and fill up the space behind it.

Here is the `<audio>` tag i am using:

```
<div class="scrub">
  <audio id="music" preload="true">
  <source src="http://www.alexkatz.me/codepen/music/interlude.mp3">
            <source src="http://www.alexkatz.me/codepen/music/interlude.ogg">
    </audio>
<div id="audioplayer">

  <div id="timeline">    
          <div id="playhead"></div>
  </div>
</div>

  </div>

  <div class="controls">
    <div id="pButton" class="play" onclick="play()"></div>
</div>
```

and my JS that I use to find the width/length of an audio file:

```
// Moves playhead as user drags
function moveplayhead(e) {
    var newMargLeft = e.pageX - timeline.offsetLeft;
    if (newMargLeft >= 0 && newMargLeft <= timelineWidth) {
        playhead.style.marginLeft = "-" + 300 + "px";
    }
    if (newMargLeft < 0) {
        playhead.style.marginLeft = "0px";
    }
    if (newMargLeft > timelineWidth) {
        playhead.style.marginLeft = timelineWidth + "px";
    }
}

// timeUpdate 
// Synchronizes playhead position with current point in audio 
function timeUpdate() {
    var playPercent =  timelineWidth * (music.currentTime / duration);
    playhead.style.marginLeft = playPercent + "px";
    if (music.currentTime == duration) {
        pButton.className = "";
        pButton.className = "play";
    }
}
```

I was using this **[tutorial](http://www.alexkatz.me/blog/html5-audio/building-a-custom-html5-audio-player-with-javascript/)** for a basis starting point.

My codepen of what I currently have can be found **[here](http://codepen.io/TyStelmach/full/b206ff78776ca95c8c01c459fbbb9eab/)**.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hi, your Codepen link is not working. If you could update that, that would be great! Thanks!

Comment: Try this **[one](http://codepen.io/TyStelmach/full/b206ff78776ca95c8c01c459fbbb9eab/)**